# In C#, is there a way to separate code that is in the same class into separate files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, oop, object

I recently inherited some code that is several thousand lines long and extremely disorganized.

I'm trying to re-factor it so that code is at least easier to find, but since it was built in visual studio, everything is contained within a single "form" class, and the way it's written makes it difficult to separate code without breaking something.

Is there a way that I could have the code live in a different file, but still keep it in the same class?

Comment: Look up "partial classes"

Comment: Why not split functions in multiple classes?

Comment: Remember to use google first: copy-pasting your title gives the answer on the first result. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514141.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Just use the `partial` keyword for each "part" of the class in the class' files.

```
// example class A in file:  A1.cs
public partial class A { }

// example class A in file:  A2.cs
public partial class A { }
```

More information can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a thousand other sites and blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using [#region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx) directive to split the code into more navigable chunks. This will also be easier to navigate to since the one file can keep the name with the class, and no one has to dig for the various pieces of this same class in different files.

Comment: Region only allows collapsing part of the file.

Comment: The problem also specifies the reason for this is a bloated, disorganized class file. Therefore, I'm offering an alternative solution, since Partial classes (the only way to split the files themselves) has already been suggested (multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This is the way Visual Stuido generates code for things like Win Forms. It enable to split the implementation into two separate files, and enables the user to alter just one and thus reducing the probability to screw something up.

The concept is called `partial classes`. You define the same class in two different files, and but class definitions need to have the word partial in font. It is also possible for `structs` and `interfaces`.

Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use partial classes. For example:

If you have a class in Example.cs as such:

```
public class Example
{
    public void Func1()
    {

    }

    public void Func2()
    {

    }

    public void Func3()
    {

    }

    public void Func4()
    {

    }
}
```

You can easily change it to:

Example.cs

```
public partial class Example
{
    public void Func2()
    {

    }

    public void Func4()
    {

    }
}
```

RestOfTheExample.cs

```
public partial class Example
{
    public void Func1()
    {

    }

    public void Func3()
    {

    }   
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

By using the partial classes as for ex

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```